# Show Git Branch Name in Terminal - MacOS Catalina - missing zsh files

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, macos-catalina

I have a fresh MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 and I'm following the steps on this link [show git branch name in terminal macos](https://medium.com/@sreedhu7/show-git-branch-name-in-terminal-macos-catalina-625a69ecb2c9) so I can display the branch name on my terminal whenever I `cd` in a git repository.

I'm in my home directory so when I run `ls -la`, I can't see any of the following files

```
.zshrc, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zprofile
```

The only relevant files showing on the list are `.bash_history` and `.zsh_history`.

Are these located on a different path or am I missing any step in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this answer on SuperUser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac/1518007#1518007), I would assume that you have to create `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, etc., on your own. As far as I can tell, you just need a `.zshrc` for what you are doing. Then you can continue with the setup from the tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

MACOS Instructions- execute the following commands in your terminal:

cd

nano .zshrc

> copy and paste this lines of code:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info

precmd() {vcs_info}

zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '(%b)'

setopt PROMPT_SUBST

PROMPT='%n> ${PWD/#$HOME/~} ${vcs_info_msg_0_}%%'
```

> CTRL+o ENTER to save and CTRL+x to exit

source .zshrc

> and that's it. Please share your configuration!

Comment: nice! i did not want to install oh my zsh just to show the git branch. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer, install **Oh My ZSH**

Trust me, you can't do a better job customizing your own `.zshrc` file.

Just go here: https://ohmyz.sh/#install

Run this command in your terminal:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Voila, you got pretty terminal outputs